# MOSFET has too large a voltage drop across drain to source

Tags: mosfet, voltage

We have a DOUT current sink circuit in one of our designs. We found that there is a 2.3 V drop across the drain to source when the MOSFET is turned ON.

As per the MOSFET's [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3099L.pdf), R<sub>DS(on)</sub> is 99 mΩ (max). Considering this resistance and a load current of 0.3 A, the drop should be 0.027 V, but it's more than that.

What could be the issue? How to resolve it? VCC_LD is 12V.

[image]

Comment: What's your gate-source voltage?

Comment: We have measured the gate voltage i.e 58.7mV when MOSFET is turn ON

Comment: Looking at the datasheet the Gate Voltage needs be at least 2V below the source.

Answer (score 6):

Since Q10 is a PMOS and you have used it on the low side, you will have a drop across it equal to the Vgs of the transistor. For small currents, it will be close to VTH which is ~1.5 V typ. As current increases, more VGS is needed and hence more drop.

You should use Q10 on the high side, i.e., above the load to avoid this drop as shown below

[image]

Other option is to use an NMOS on the low side and invert its gate control. Make sure that you use an NMOS which has a low enough RDS when the GPIO is driving high on the NMOS gate.

[image]

Comment: As My understanding, the P-MOSFET gate is needed negative voltage for complete conduction...since we are providing a voltage near Zero i.e 58.7mV, this would reason for more RDS than mentioned in the datasheet value. This may be the reason for the voltage drop I guess, is this correct? With the existing circuit, How can I eliminate this voltage drop? is there any way?

Comment: @Chitharanjan, I am not sure you understood my answer. So, I have added some diagrams to help you. This is not an RDS issue that you are facing. The drop is because of VGS limitation. In this configuration, gate = 0V. So, source cannot go lower than say 2V because you need a VGS for the PMOS to turn ON.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the 2.3V drop in the existing design, without moving the MOSFET higher side? The reason of connected the MOSFET on the higher side because Since this MOSFET circuit is working as a sinking circuit other vice it act as source circuit if we add the MOSFET in lower side

Comment: @Chitharanjan, no other clean option other than the above 2 ideas. One crazy idea would be to short out the PMOS if you can keep the load ON always.

Comment: OK understood, can you please elaborate a little more on the PMOS VGS limit for understanding the working?

Comment: Please read about PMOS working (Current equation in saturation). For current to pass through a PMOS in saturation, VS-VG = |VTHp| + VON.  You have VG=VD=0V. So, VS will be |VTHp| + VON. Where VON is called the overdrive voltage that depends on the current flowing. This |VTHp| + VON is ~2.3V in your case. When you move the PMOS to the high side, VS-VG becomes 12V because VS=12V and VG=0V. So, there is no VGS limitation. Here the PMOS is working in linear region and now, the drop will depend on RDS